# Top 5 movies with most number of ratings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently facing a little problem. I'm working with the movie-lens 1M data, and trying to get the top 5 movies with the most ratings.

```
movies = pandas.read_table('movies.dat', sep='::', header=None, names= ['movie_id', 'title', 'genre'])
users = pandas.read_table('users.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=['user_id', 'gender','age','occupation_code','zip'])
ratings = pandas.read_table('ratings.dat', sep='::', header=None, names=['user_id','movie_id','rating','timestamp'])

movie_data = pandas.merge(movies,pandas.merge(ratings,users))
```

The above code is what I have written to merge the .dat files into one Dataframe.
Then I need the top 5 from that movie_data dataframe, based on the ratings.

Here is what I have done:

```
print(movie_data.sort('rating', ascending = False).head(5))
```

This seem to find the top 5 based on the rating. However, the output is:

```
        movie_id              title                        genre  user_id  \
0              1   Toy Story (1995)  Animation|Children's|Comedy        1   
657724      2409    Rocky II (1979)                 Action|Drama      101   
244214      1012  Old Yeller (1957)             Children's|Drama      447   
657745      2409    Rocky II (1979)                 Action|Drama      549   
657752      2409    Rocky II (1979)                 Action|Drama      684   

    rating  timestamp gender  age  occupation_code    zip  
0            5  978824268      F    1               10  48067  
657724       5  977578472      F   18                3  33314  
244214       5  976236279      F   45               11  55105  
657745       5  976119207      M   25                6  53217  
657752       5  975603281      M   25                4  27510
```

As you can see Rocky II appears 3 times. I would like to know if I can somehow remove duplicates fast, other than going through the list again, and remove duplicates that way.

I have looked at a pivot_table, but i'm not quite sure how they work, so if it can be done with such a table, i need some explaination of how they work

EDIT.
First comment did indeed remove the duplicates.

```
movie_data.drop_duplicates(subset='movie_id').sort('rating', ascending = False).head(5)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: IIUC you can do `movie_data.drop_duplicates(subset='movie_id').sort('rating', ascending = False).head(5)`

Comment: That did indeed drop the duplicates :) Thanks a lot. Rocky II is not in the output anymore however ^^. But i guess that's just random because they all have a rating of 5. But i will look into it :)

Comment: It seems that you get not 5 top-rated movies but 5 movies that were rated 5 at least once. That is why you had Rocky three time - at least three persons rated it with 5 (and i can even tell their gender, age occupation code and zip ;)

Comment: Indeed. I'm currently looking at it :) But my original question did get answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the duplicate entries by calling [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) and pass param `subset='movie_id'`:

```
movie_data.drop_duplicates(subset='movie_id').sort('rating', ascending = False).head(5)
```